# Remove double quotes from fts keywords?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I need indexing JSON values with fulltext index.

In Oracle:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON tab_name (json_col_name)
  INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
  PARAMETERS ('section group CTXSYS.JSON_SECTION_GROUP SYNC (ON COMMIT)');
```

In SQL Server:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON tab_name (json_col_name)
        KEY INDEX primary_key_name
        ON ft_cat_name
        [other options...];
```

Both of indexes are created successfully. But when I do some query with those indexes, I take some troubles in SQL.
When I try to find the reason, I found that's caused by word-breaker.

Word-breaker keeps unnecessary characters (double quote, colon) of all FIELDS and VALUES in json text as INDEX KEYWORDS.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords  (DB_ID('db_name'), OBJECT_ID('tab_name'))
```

Is there anybody faced this problem? And how to resolve?

I want to know how to config word-breakers to remove unnecessary characters from keywords when populate indexes in SQL.

Comment: Can you provide an example query that isn't working so I can understand your problem better? Also, SQL Server doesn't typically store punctuation characters in the full text data so I'm curious to know what language your index is using and if there are any custom word breakers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried indexing these columns with neutral language (LCID = 0) and all unnecessary symbols in JSON string are removed from the keywords.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON tab_name (json_col_name language 0)
    KEY INDEX primary_key_name
    ON ft_cat_name
    [other options...];
```